# How can I fix my line-endings mess?

Tags: git, core.autocrlf

Don't know how it happened, but on one machine (Windows), I have a personal.el file (text) with CRLF-Endings, while on the other it has LF endings. There might be a few other differences in this file on both machines.

Now when I pull the latest changes (made on the windows machine) on the linux machine, git tells me it's a huuuuuge diff, because every line differs in the line ending.

I understood that .gitattributes or core.autocrlf is there for exactly that case. However, I tried several settings, but none really helped.

In .gitattributes, I tried (line by line, not all at once, of course):

```
personal.el text eol=auto
personal.el text eol=lf
personal.el text
```

For autocrlf, I tried `git config --global core.autocrlf input`.

What's the correct setup for my case?
Any other possibilities besides changing line endings?

Comment: What did you set in .gitattributes and in core.autocrlf?

Comment: My .gitattributes is `* text=auto` and the only thing that *might* be relevant in my linux git config is `core.filemode=true`.  My windows machine has `core.autocrlf=true`, though.  No issues with line endings here.  (Unless I accidentally use WSL bash to check in files from my Windows machine)

Comment: Don't change `core.filemode`.  It's not a setting, it's _cached information_ of how your filesystem behaves.

Comment: @EdwardThomson - Yikes.  That's good info :)

Comment: What does `git ls-files --eol personal.el` say?